# Can i run a second web server?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, raspberry-pi2

So i own a raspberry pi server which runs a python web server i want to run a second web server on the pi but im not sure if it can handle it.

Raspberry pi 2 model B,
Python 3,
Ubuntu Software,

Comment: What is the issue? Did you try it? You can just start another python program but listen on another port...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, you can.

Long answer: It depends on what your web servers will be doing and how good your internet is. I have a RasPi 4 running OctoPrint, a few bots and some other misc. stuff. Also, you may run into problems along the lines of your web servers trying to listen for connections on the same port, which is another problem outside the scope of your initial question.